# Hide / show images inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, upload, html5-canvas

I'm making a page where I want people to be able to overlapp images and then upload them to my server.

I've built the uploading page and I've put two test images in a canvas. The only issue noe is to be able to hide / show these two images through a button or checkbox.

I've uploaded a test page here: http://kaosmos.no/bokbodentest2/upload.html

This is my code for the canvas:

```
<input type="checkbox"/>Check to hide img1
<input type="checkbox"/>Check to hide img2


<img class="bilder" id="img1" src="test1.png">
<img class="bilder" id="img2" src="test2.png">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = img1.width;
canvas.height = img1.height;

context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);


</script>
```

And CSS:

```
canvas {
border: solid;
overflow: hidden;
}

canvas img {
width: 600px;
position: absolute;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.bilder {
display: none;
}
```

The display: none; in the "bilder" class is so that the images won't be visable outside the canvas. How do I make a function to hide / show these images?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to show/hide them *on the canvas* or outside of it?

Comment: Once the image is drawn to the canvas, it is no longer linked to the original element in the DOM. If you want to hide it on the canvas, you'll need to redraw the canvas without the context.drawImage call.

Comment: @MattMokary I want to show / hide it on the canvas, so that the user can "compose" their own combination.

Comment: @AndrewLeedham Do you have any code examples on how to do this? :)

Comment: Maybe something like this could work?

`code

$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#checkbox1").is(":checked")) {
            var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        } 


        else if ($("#checkbox1").not(":checked")) {
           context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since when an image is drawn to the canvas, it is no longer linked to the original element in the DOM, you want to hide it on the canvas, so you'll need to redraw the canvas each time an input is changed, not calling the relevant context.drawImage function. Something along these lines:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="draw()"/>Check to hide img1
<input type="checkbox" onchange="draw()"/>Check to hide img2


<img class="bilder" id="img1" src="test1.png">
<img class="bilder" id="img2" src="test2.png">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

canvas.width = img1.width;
canvas.height = img1.height;
function draw(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    if(inputs[0].checked){
        context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    }
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
    if(inputs[1].checked){
        context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This sort of works! Only problem is that now the checkbox shows both images. Is it possible to separate them so that each image has it's own checkbox?

I've updated the test page with this code: http://kaosmos.no/bokbodentest2/upload.html

Comment: My bad: typo. Just replace `if(inputs[0].checked){` with `if(inputs[1].checked){` I've edited it in the main answer

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!!